# How do I exclude the "fingerprint" field from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using the `fingerprint` filter in Logstash to create a *fingerprint* field that I set to `document_id` in the `elasticsearch` output.

Configuration is as follows:

```
filter {
  fingerprint {
    method => "SHA1"
    key => "KEY"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => localhost
    document_id => "%{fingerprint}"
  }
}
```

This results in a redundant `fingerprint` field in Elasticsearch that's the same value as `_id`.  How do I prevent this redundant field from being saved to ES?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using logstash 1.5 or higher, you can put your field in [metadata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html#metadata) and then it will not be sent to elasticsearch as part of the regular message.

#### Example:

```
filter {
  fingerprint {
    ...
    target => "[@metadata][fingerprint]"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    ...
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][fingerprint]}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like what I was looking for.  Edited your answer to include an example.

Comment: Lifesaver tip. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You could set the `document_id` as the [fingerprint target](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/1.5/plugins-filters-fingerprint.html#plugins-filters-fingerprint-target)

```
filter {
  fingerprint {
    method => "SHA1"
    key => "KEY"
    target => "document_id"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to where it says ES will treat the `document_id` field on the document as the document's *ID*? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/1.5/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-document_id

Comment: I figured the elasticsearch plugin would take it automatically from the fields like it takes the type. Guess that is not the case